# Using v-if to show an html element based on the value of a variable

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to show a `<div>` element (that contains a few nested `<div>`s) based on the value of a variable.  I'm using v-if (though if there's a better way to go about it, please let me know).

I tried wrapping the whole `<div>` in a `<template v-if>` (per [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html's](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html%27s) suggestion), but that didn't work, and I used devtools to verify that my variable is being accurately set.

```
<div v-if="myVar == 'option1' || 'option2'" class="...
     <div>...
     </div>
</div>
```

Even when `myVar` doesn't equal `option 1` or `option 2`, the element is still visible.

EDIT: I added `v-if="myVar=='option1'"` to an `<img>` and it is acting as intended - is there something about `or(||)` that I'm using incorrectly?

Comment: If you need to use several different values and the attribute starts getting really long just use `v-if="computedVar"'` and create a computed property with the same content as your attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, `||` produces the value of first operand if it is a truthy value or the value of the second operand if first is not truthy.
Therefore, `'option1' || 'option2'` will always produce `'option1'` (read below).

---

A few considerations:

1. Never use [reserved words](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1) (i.e: `var`) to name your functions or variables.
2. the expression `'option1' || 'option2'` will always return `'option1'`, as `'option1'` is a `String` with `length` greater than `0`, therefore a truthy expression. You might be looking for

```js
v-if="['option1', 'option2'].indexOf(varName) > -1"
```

... which is equivalent to

```
v-if="varName === 'option1' || varName === 'option2'"
```

...where `varName` is the variable holding whatever you have put in your `var` - which needs renaming (to `varName` or any other name of your choice, except a reserved word).

3. Avoid using loose comparisons at all costs. (Use `===` instead of `==`). They open the door to extremely difficult to trace bugs. It's way better to cast your variables to a particular type then to allow them to have multiple types of values.
4. It is considered good practice to use computed properties or methods when the condition becomes long (a good rule of thumb is: when you need more than 2 operands, use a computed/method).
   Computed properties are used when you don't need to pass in any arguments while methods allow passing arguments (i.e.: the current item inside a `v-for`).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to list `myVar` twice (as follows).  It is now working as desired.
    
    `<div v-if="myVar=='option1'||myVar=='option2'" class="...
         <div>...
         </div>
    </div>`